# How create carousel in Episerver?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, episerver-7

I created carousel using this one tutorial [Per Zimmerman animation tutorial](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/pezi/Dates/2013/5/Create-an-animating-slider-with-content-area/) and its works fine, but this tutorial is for web forms. Now I installed Alloy MVC site using Deployment Center. And I would like to create the same carousel for MVC and using bootstrap. Can somebody provide me with documentation how create carousel in Episerver MVC site using bootstrap ?
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you posted this same question on EPiWorld and found a solution.  Can you post that Solution here?  http://world.episerver.com/Forum/Developer-forum/-EPiServer-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2014/8/How-to-create-image-carousel-as-block/

Comment: @PhilipPittle yes , sure. I forgot about this one question

Comment: Excellent, I think this will have some value for the EPi community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question here [EpiServer World](http://world.episerver.com/Forum/Developer-forum/-EPiServer-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2014/8/How-to-create-image-carousel-as-block/)  The answer is: Per Zimmerman tutorial is for Web Forms, but I tryied to implement it in MVC Site. Thats why it doesnt work. But you can create carousel using ContentArea in MVC Site. You should create for example block with one field Image and than add few blocks to ContentArea. After that you can get that blocks in controller and display images in View!